# by completing the square find in terms of k the roots of the equation $x^2 + 2kx-7=0$

Tags: quadratics

By completing the square find in terms of $k$ the roots of the equation $$x^2 + 2kx-7=0$$
prove for all real values of $k$, the roots are real

Comment: $(x+k)^2 -k^2-7=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+2kx-7=x^2+2\cdot x\cdot k+k^2-k^2-7=0$$
$$(x+k)^2=k^2+7$$
$$x+k=\pm\sqrt{k^2+7}$$
$$x=-k\pm\sqrt{k^2+7}$$
because $k^2+7\geq 0$ for all real $k$ all roots are real.